# Populate a select with options sorted alphabetically

Tags: javascript

I need to populate a select tag with elements from JSON Object `modeles_by_selected_marque` : My select need to be filled with all the `a_libellemodele` attributes:

[image]

Here is how I populated my select :

```
select_modele = document.getElementById( 'ilibellemodelecibletm' );

for(var i = 0; i < modeles_by_selected_marque.length; i++) {
            select_modele.add( new Option( modeles_by_selected_marque[i]['a_libellemodele'] + "  |  " +modeles_by_selected_marque[i]['codemodele'] ) );
        };
```

The code works fine but I just have an issue, my options are not sorted alphabetically, I know that order in javascript Object can be tricky, so how can I fix this ? Thank you

Comment: Seems `modeles_by_selected_marque` is an *array of objects*. Sorting arrays works just fine, so simply sort it as desired before using it to create/populate the options.

Comment: @Yoshi Can you be more specific ?

Comment: In you question you state: *"I know that order in javascript Object can be tricky, ..."* That might be true in the sense that the inherent order of object properties is not defined, and as such attempts to order them will yield different results. But what you have is not simply an object, rather an ***array** of objects*, and arrays are perfectly [sortable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Meaning, sort it as required, and then create the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash to sort your array:

```
modeles_by_selected_marque = _.orderBy(modeles_by_selected_marque, 'a_libellemodele', 'asc');
```